# php preg_match regex special pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to use preg_match to get some part of a string and use them later. 
I'm not really good at using regex so, i hope you can help me with it.

My current regex :

```
$regex = '/(?P<name>\w+): (?P<agency>\w+)/';
```

My code so far:

```
$mail = imap_qprint(imap_body($mbox, $msgno)); 

$regex = '/(?P<name>\w+): (?P<agency>\w+)/';

preg_match($regex, $mail, $agency);
print_r($agency);
```

To keep it simple $mail looks like this (as an example):

```
Agency : Aname
Firstname : Fname
Lastname: Lname
Number of participant : 1
```

and i would like to get an array in $agency that can give me the Agency, First name and Last name, and with another regex (because i don't know if it's possible in only one) to get the number of participant.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With preg_match_all and `(?P<name>.+)[:](?P<value>.+)` you would get:

```
$matches Array:
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Agency 
            [1] => Firstname 
            [2] => Lastname
            [3] => Number of participant 
        )

    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Aname
            [1] =>  Fname
            [2] =>  Lname
            [3] =>  1
```

You could read these off as

```
$data = array();
foreach($matches['name'] as $id => $name) {
    $data[$name] = trim($matches['value'][$id]);
}
```

Which would give you a key => value called $data with all the information.

EDIT: To make it a little more robust I would recommend using the multi-line flag and adding ^ and $ to your regex

```
preg_match_all('#^(?P<name>.+)[:](?P<value>.+)$#m',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about: 
`$regex = '/Agency\s*:\s*(\w+).*?Firstname\s*:\s*(\w+).*?Lastname:\s*(\w+).*?Number of participant\s*:\s*(\d+)/s'`